# Can't plot points on the Bloch sphere (QuTip)

Tags: programming, qutip

I have the really odd problem when it comes to plotting Bloch spheres using QuTip. Plotting state vectors works perfectly fine e.g.

```
from qutip import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = Bloch()
s = Qobj([[1],[0]])
b.add_states(s)
b.show()
```

But when I try to plot points on the Bloch sphere using QuTiP

```
from qutip import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = Bloch()
pnt = [1,1,1]
b.add_points(pnt)
b.show()
```

I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 80, in _draw
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 292, in draw
    reverse=True)):
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 291, in <lambda>
    key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 545, in do_3d_projection
    ecs = (_zalpha(self._edgecolor3d, vzs) if self._depthshade else
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 847, in _zalpha
    rgba = np.broadcast_to(mcolors.to_rgba_array(colors), (len(zs), 4))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in broadcast_to
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 182, in broadcast_to
    return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
  File "/Users/turbotanten/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 127, in _broadcast_to
    op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (0,4) and requested shape (2,4)
```

I have tried using different matplotlib backends like TkAgg without any success. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem here https://github.com/qutip/qutip/issues/1027

Apparently plotting points on the Bloch sphere does not work with Matplotlib v3.1.0.
So I had to downgrade to v.3.0.3 for it to work!